# Case Insensitive variable for String replaceAll(,) method Java

Tags: java, regex, string

Can anyone help me with creating a regex for variables in java so that the string variable will be considered to be a case insensitive and replace each and every word like Access, access, etc with WINDOWS of any thing like that?

This is the code:

```
$html=html.replaceAll(label, "WINDOWS");
```

Notice that label is a string variable.

Comment: Why not simply add a case-insensitive String to the label String? `"(?i)"`

Comment: @pst: sorry, got it wrong. Edited my comment.

Comment: Perhaps also note what replaceAll takes as a first argument... then post it as an answer? ;-)

Comment: @pst: I have to run and don't have time to test this. I'll leave it to you to post the tested answer.

Comment: Is this a Java code? The `$` confuses me a bit :-)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to replace case-insensitive literal substrings in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5054995/how-to-replace-case-insensitive-literal-substrings-in-java)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Just add the "case insensitive" switch to the regex:

```
html.replaceAll("(?i)"+label, "WINDOWS");
```

Note: If the label could contain characters with special regex significance, eg if label was `".*"`, but you want the label treated as plain text (ie not a regex), add regex quotes around the label, either

```
html.replaceAll("(?i)\\Q" + label + "\\E", "WINDOWS");
```

or

```
html.replaceAll("(?i)" + Pattern.quote(label), "WINDOWS");
```

Answer (score 8):

String.replaceAll is equivalent to creating a matcher and calling its replaceAll method so you can do something like this to make it case insensitive:

```
html = Pattern.compile(label, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE).matcher(html).replaceAll("WINDOWS");
```

See: [String.replaceAll](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) and 
[Pattern.compile](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#compile%28java.lang.String,%20int%29) JavaDocs

Comment: Is there a significant impact on memory / performance when using case insensitive (in opposition to Java's default case sensitive replace() method) for large Strings? For example, a document containing predefined labels (variables) that can be replaced dynamically based on some app logic.

Answer (score 1):

Just use patterns and matcher. Here's the code

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("Your word", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
Matcher m = p.matcher("String containing words");
String result = m.replaceAll("Replacement word");
```

Using patterns is easy as they are not case insensitive.

For more information, see

[Matchmaking with regular expressions](http://www.javaworld.com/jw-07-2001/jw-0713-regex.html)

[Java: Pattern and Matcher](http://www.leepoint.net/notes-java/data/strings/40regular_expressions/26pattern-matcher.html)

Comment: How come this is any different? str.replaceAll(reg, replacement) is exactly the same as Pattern.compile(reg).matcher(str).replaceAll(replacement)

Comment: Using matcher is case insensitive. See the article in javaworld

Comment: @SriHarshaChilakapati "It depends". Compare with anttix's answer.

Comment: @pst Sorry, but I didn't see his. I had spent some time in writing the answer and in search of the links

Answer (score -1):

I think but am not sure you want label to be something like `[Aa][cC][cC][eE][sS][sS]`

or alternatively do

```
html = Pattern.compile(lable, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE)
        .matcher(html).replaceAll("WINDOWS");
```