# Highlighting search term in ListView while keeping original case

Tags: android, regex

I have a ListView and a search_term. I want to highlight (by coloring red) all instances of the search_term in the ListView. This works and is easy.

```
text = text.replaceAll(search_term, "<font color='red'>$1</font>");
```

I am now trying to make it work in a case in-sensitive manor.
I thought the following was correct but it is not working.

```
text = text.replaceAll("(?i)" + search_term, "<font color='red'>$1</font>");
```

SO basically I want to color all instances of the search_term in red, I want to ignore case when matching but not when coloring.

Here are 3 examples. The search_term is "apple" and bold represents the color red.

"The apple is red" -> "The **apple** is red"

"The Apple is red" -> "The **Apple** is red"

"The APPLE is red" -> "The **APPLE** is red"

Kind Regards,
Cathal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The search_term should be in round bracket like `()` which depicts a `group`..

So for apple your search_term should be

```
search_term="(apple)";
```

This would get captured in `$1`

**OR**

You can simply use `$0` without using `()`

**NOTE**

`$0`->is the complete match

`$1`->first `()` group

`$2`->second `()` group

Comment: Wow, thank you, using 0 as the index worked.

title = title.replaceAll("(?i)" + filterText, "<font color='red'>$0</font>");

Answer (score 0):

I don't think `(?i)` works with `String.replaceAll`.  It should work if you use [Pattern](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) and [Matcher](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/regex/Matcher.html).

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile( search_term, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE );
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher( text );
text = matcher.replaceAll( "\0" );
```

I'm not 100% sure I have the string in `replaceAll` right, but that's the general idea.

Comment: (?i) does work with String.replaceALL
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5054995/how-to-replace-case-insensitive-literal-substrings-in-java