# How to count occurrence of each character in the alphabet with a file

Tags: java

I would like to know how to go about starting a program that reads in a file and goes line by line counting the occurrence of each letter in the alphabet.I know I would like to use an array that holds the alphabets, but I am not sure how to go about reading each line and then printing the count out for each alphabetical occurrence.

Comment: What do you have so far?

Comment: nothing right now, but the code that reads in the file. I'm trying to get an idea where to start

Comment: Well, there are plenty of tutorials about reading files and printing arrays and the question about finding character occurrences in a String gets asked twice a week. I guess there shouldn't be a problem finding and using that stuff.

Comment: [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) - If you don't know how to do a certain part, at least provide the parts that you know how to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
  BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("somefile.txt"));
    int ch;
    char charToSearch='a';
    int counter=0;
    while((ch=reader.read()) != -1) {
        if(charToSearch == (char)ch) {
            counter++;
        }
    };
    reader.close();

    System.out.println(counter);
```

Reference: [Counting letter occurrence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15021163/counting-letter-occurrence)

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
public void countOccurence() {
 BufferedReader reader
                     = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("somefile.txt"));

String text = "";
while((ch=reader.read()) != -1) {
       text = text +ch;
    };
    reader.close();


 for(Character a :"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789".toCharArray())
    {

         int ch;
         char charToSearch=a;
         int counter=0;
         for(Character b : text.toCharArray())
            {
              if(charToSearch == (char)b) {
                counter++;
                  }
            }

    System.out.pritln("Character: " +charToSearch+ " occurs " + counter 
    + " times.");

         }
    }
```

Mark as up, if it works for you :)

Comment: You're reading the whole file `36` times? Yes, very good idea.

Answer (score 0):

```
    public void count() throws Exception {
        int[] array = new int[26];
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("file.txt"));
        int ch;
        while((ch = br.read()) != -1) {
            if (ch > 64 && ch < 97) // Upper case letters
                ch += 32; // to get the ascii value of the letter in lowercase
            if(-1 < ch-97 && ch-97 < 26)
                array[ch-97] += 1;
        }
        br.close();
        int i = 0;
        for (char chr = 'a'; chr <= 'z'; chr++) {
            System.out.printf("%s --> %d\n", chr, array[i]);
            i++;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("somefile.txt"));
int ch; 
Map<char, int> charCount = new Map<char, int>();
while((ch=reader.read()) != -1) {
    if(charCount.contains(ch)) {
        charCount.put(ch, charCount.get(ch)++);
    } else {
        charCount.put(ch, 1);
    }
}
reader.close();

for(String key: charCount.keySet())
    System.out.println(key + " - " + charCount.get(key));
System.out.println();
```

This will keep a counter for EVERY character in the file. If you want to limit this set to an alphabet, this can be done easily by checking is `ch` is in the alphabet before putting it in `charCount`.