# How to do a case-insensitive string replacement

Tags: java, android, android-emulator

Hi friends I'm creating an app.
I want to find a particular word in an `ArrayList` and I have to replace
it with another word. I used the code below. It works case sensitive,
but I'd like to get it working case insensitive.

```
   FillintheBlank.class: 

          public class FillintheBlank extends Activity {
        static ArrayList<String> multiword=new ArrayList<String>();

 static ArrayList<String> multimeaning=new ArrayList<String>();


public void setNoTitle() {
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
} 
 float screenHeight,screenWidth,screendensity;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setNoTitle();
     getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
     DisplayMetrics displaymetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
     getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displaymetrics);
     screenHeight = displaymetrics.heightPixels;
     screenWidth = displaymetrics.widthPixels;
     screendensity = displaymetrics.densityDpi;
    setContentView(R.layout.fillinblanknew);

             multiword.add("radha");
             multiword.add("RAdHA");
              multiword.add("latha");
                multiword.add("mammu");

              s.o.p(""+multiword);
            // output:radha,RADHA,latha,mamu

          multimeaning.add(multiword.getString().replace(radha,"sai"));
        s.o.p(""+multimeaning);
     // output: sai,RADHA,latha,mamu

 }
  }
```

For example: I need to replace 'radha' with 'sai' no matter what the case of the letters in 'radha' are.

Comment: http://jelaniharris.com/2009/case-insensitive-replaceall-in-java/

Comment: And another example on StackOverflow: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5054995/how-to-replace-case-insensitive-literal-substrings-in-java

Comment: Is this your actual working code? How are you doing a getString() on an ArrayList?

Comment: thankyou somuch stackoverfolw link is working for me...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Could use a regular expression. 
Just add (?i) before your string to ignore case.

So for example:

> multiword.getString().replaceAll ( "(?i)radha", "sai");

Comment: You're right, I don't think replace takes a regex, only replaceAll and replaceFirst

Answer (score 1):

You can "(?i)" pattern in front of a string to ignore the case.

```
public class StringReplace {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(replaceString("This is a FISH", "IS"));
    }

    public static String replaceString(String first, String second) {
          return first.replaceAll("(?i)"+ second, "");
    }
}
```

The code above will return "Th  a FH".

Answer (score 0):

Use StringUtils by **apache commons lang3 - v3.5 or later** (so you don't have to worry about regular expression parsing):

```
StringUtils.replaceIgnoreCase(text, searchString, replacement);
```

or:

```
StringUtils.replaceOnceIgnoreCase(text, searchString, replacement);
```

If you use maven, add this dependency (I'm using version 3.6):

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-lang3 -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
    <version>3.6</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score -4):

You could use `equalsIgnoreCase(string)` method found in String class for your purpose.

Comment: yes i tried.please see my code once. first i need to search in arraylist that string is there or then i have to apply that equlasignore case() butin  above code how to apply that method i didnt get any idea

Comment: @TimothyP OP wants insensitive case replace. Not equals. If I am wrong in downvoting, I will undo it. But I think the answer is not proper.

Comment: Well, his answer may have been better as a comment now that I think of it. You're correct