# Replace String ignoring case in Java

Tags: java, regex, string, replace

```
String Checkout = D:\ifs\APP\Checkout
String DeleteLine = D:\IFS\APP\Checkout\trvexp\client\Ifs.App\text.txt
```

Note the **ifs** and **IFS** in both Strings.
I want to replace the **Checkout String** in the **Deleted Line**

So the final String would look like this:

```
\trvexp\client\Ifs.App\text.txt
```

Following is what I have tried, but obviously due to Case Sensitivity, the string won't get replaced. Any Solution or a work around for this?

```
String final = DeleteLine.replace(Checkout, "");
```

Comment: Do you know which characters may be uppercase? Check http://stackoverflow.com/q/5054995/928952 and http://stackoverflow.com/q/15613209/928952

Comment: Add a "(?i)" to your checkout string and then try replaceAll()

Comment: @Danielson Only the word IFS

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`String.replace()` doesn't support regex. You need `String.replaceAll()`.

```
DeleteLine.replaceAll("(?i)" + Pattern.quote(Checkout), "");
```

Comment: you may use `replaceFirst` also.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This worked :) I'll accept the answer in a minute

Answer (score 3):

Put `(?i)` in the `replaceAll` method's regular expression:

```
String finalString = DeleteLine.replaceAll("(?i)" + Checkout, "");
```

Comment: It's probably worth using `Pattern.quote` with `Checkout` as well, otherwise it won't mean what the OP really wants it to.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this:

```
String Checkout = "D:\\\\ifs\\\\APP\\\\Checkout";
String DeleteLine = "D:\\IFS\\APP\\Checkout\\trvexp\\client\\Ifs.App\\text.txt";
String f = DeleteLine.replaceFirst("(?i)"+Checkout, "");
```

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, if youi want the pattern on a specific portion you can do it manually. You can declare the checkout Sting as:

```
String Checkout= \Q(?i)D:\ifs\APP\Checkout\E
```

as

> \Q means "start of literal text"
>   \E means"end of literal text"

and then do the replace

```
String final = DeleteLine.replace(Checkout, "");
```