# How to replace XML tag in String? (also checking if it starts with xml tag)

Tags: java, xml, string, xls

1. I need to replace a XML tag in string. The problem is that some of responses don't give me XML tag `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>` in the beginning and some of them
   do.
2. There are responses, who have uppercase and lowercase letters. So if I match with **String.replace()** it ignores it.
3. I need to add XLS tag to that response. (currently working)

Response 1. Without XML tag in the beginning

```
<records>
  <message>Something was found</message>
</records>
```

Response 2. With XML tag (from another service)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<records>
  <message>Nothing found</message>
</records>
```

Response 3. With XML tag (lowercase utf-8)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<records>
  <message>Nothing found</message>
</records>
```

When I add XLS tags, the final product needs to look like this:

```
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="C:\Template.xsl"?>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<records>
  <message>Nothing found</message>
</records>
```

At the moment I was using **String.replace()**, and matched

```
String xlsSchema = "<?xml-stylesheet type=\"text/xsl\" href=\"" + template.getAbsolutePath() + "\"?>";
String replacable = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>";
String finalTags = replacable  + xlsSchema;
result = integrationResponse.replace(replacable, finalTags);
```

- the problem with *'replacable'* is that some of responses give me uppercase and some lowercase letters. Using `.toUppercase() || .toLowerCase()` is not an option, because it affects all xml response.

Is there a way, that I can create following expression?
If it *starts with OR contains* `"<?xml"` tag in the beginning, then only add XLS before it and if **!contains**, then add XLS schema + XML tag?

**SOLVED!** [comment here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32453577/3433040)

Comment: What's the context here? Usually any messing around with the string representation of an XML document is a really bad idea... just parse the XML in an XML API and use the result.

Comment: Take a look here http://stackoverflow.com/a/5055036/529256 Demonstrates case insensative find/replace.

Comment: @Kefirchiks You should put that as an answer to your question, its illegible in the comments area. Also, I'm glad I could help, please upvote my response. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**SOLVED!**
Did this /w regex.

```
String xlsSchema = "<?xml-stylesheet type=\"text/xsl\" href=\"" + template.getAbsolutePath() + "\"?>";
String newTag = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>";
String tag = "<?xml";
String strippedXML = "";

// Remove all XML tags from beginning
if (integrationResponse.toLowerCase().contains(tag)) {
    strippedXML = integrationResponse.replaceAll("<\\?[^>]*\\?>", "");
    result = newTag + xlsSchema + strippedXML;
}
else 
    result = newTag + xlsSchema + integrationResponse;
```

Answer (score 0):

you can change integrationResponse to uppercase like this :

```
result = integrationResponse.toUppercase().replace(replacable.toUppercase(),finalTags);
result_ = result.toLowerCase() ;
```