# Java Regex ReplaceAll on range -> String.replaceAll() on string X after (not including) some char Y ~> until (including) end of case-ignored string Z

Tags: java, regex, substring, match, replaceall

I am trying to replace all instances of a substring from the first character following ":" until the end of a substring "user" with case-ignored using the `(?i)`

So, an example would be:

**Input**

```
u:sdneUSER|r:endsUser(&g:againuser)
```

Replace All :

```
sdneUSER -> root
endsUser -> root
againuser -> root
```

**Expected Output:**

```
u:root|r:root(&g:root)
```

Reference :

Ignore case https://stackoverflow.com/a/5055036

Comment: you should at least try

Comment: Your question only contains requirements - it is not showing any efforts from your side to solve this problem yourself. Please add your attempts to this questions - as this site is not a free "we do your (home)work" service. Beyond that: please turn to the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) to learn how/what to ask here. Thanks

Comment: Please show what you have tried. This site is great at helping you improve what you have done but no so good at doing the work for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this regex `:.*?(?=[^a-zA-Z]+)` with replaceAll like this :

```
String text = "u:sdneUSER|r:endsUser(&g:againuser)";
text = text.replaceAll(":.*?(?=[^a-zA-Z]+)", ":root");
```

**Output**

```
u:root|r:root(&g:root)
```

---

[<kbd>regex demo</kbd>](https://regex101.com/r/FIL4ZF/1)