# how to use replace function in java for case insensitive character value

Tags: java

I am writing a java program in which a user enters a series of words that changes every ‘p’ to a ‘b’  in the sentence (case insensitive) and displays the output.

I try to use replace function but it is not case insensitive

```
String result = s.replace('p', 'b');
```

I expect the output `boliticians bromised`, but the actual outputs is `Politicians bromised`.

Comment: can you use replace twice for p and P?

Answer (score 1):

`replace` is case sensitive only.

There is no "simple" way to do this: you could do two replacements, but that constructs an intermediate string.

```
String result = s.replace('p', 'b').replace('P', 'B');
```

I would do this by iterating the character array:

```
char[] cs = s.toCharArray();
for (int i = 0; i < cs.length; ++i) {
  switch (cs[i]) {
    case 'p': cs[i] = 'b'; break;
    case 'P': cs[i] = 'B'; break;
  }
}
String result = new String(cs);
```

If you wanted to write a method to do this for non-hardcoded letters, you could do it like:

```
String method(String s, char from, char to) {
  char ucFrom = Character.toUpperCase(from);  // Careful with locale.
  char ucTo = Character.toUpperCase(to);

  char[] cs = s.toCharArray();
  for (int i = 0; i < cs.length; ++i) {
    if (cs[i] == from) { cs[i] = to; }
    else if (cs[i] == ucFrom) { cs[i] = ucTo; }
  }
  return new String(cs);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using regex, see Q&A -
[How to replace case-insensitive literal substrings in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5054995/how-to-replace-case-insensitive-literal-substrings-in-java)
or you can use replace twice for p and P

Answer (score 0):

You can use `replaceAll` instead so you can use a regular expression:

```
String result = s.replaceAll("[pP]", "b");
```