# IndexOf in for loop only removes one character

Tags: java

I want to use IndexOf inside a for loop so I can remove all instances of a word/character in a phrase, but my code only deletes the first instance even if I think it should remove the others.
Here is my code:

```
    String phrase = "yes no YES NO";
    String del = "no";
    for (int i=0;i<phrase.length();i++) {
        if (phrase.indexOf(del) == i) {
            System.out.print("");
        }
        else 
            System.out.print(phrase.charAt(i));
    }
```

The code above gives me this result:

```
yes o YES NO
```

I want my code to give me

```
yes YES
```

but I don't understand why indexOf only removes one character and I don't understand how I can use .equalsIgnoreCase with my string to also remove "NO". How should I change my code to get this answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`indexOf` is used in order to find a specific **character** in a String. If you'd like to remove a specific value within a String, I suggest using the `replaceAll` method.

Also, note that both `indexOf` and `replaceAll` are case-sensitive. That means that "no" and "NO" are different, since "NO" is upper-cased (that's also the reason the "NO" is left untouched).

Use `target.replaceAll("(?i)" + Pattern.quote("text"), "");` for a case-insensitive variant (as explained in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5054995/how-to-replace-case-insensitive-literal-substrings-in-java) post).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
String newPhrase = phrase.replaceAll(del," ");
```

and then print newPhrase.

Also, "no" and "NO" are two different values. one is uppercase and the other is lower case. so if you don't want your code to be case sensitive, you need to check for the lowercase of "del" in the lowercase of "phrase".