# Find phrases from a text file in Java

Tags: java, string, hashmap, replaceall

The goal is I am reading in a text file and finding certain words to replace. It will then replace the words and output a new text file that has the words replaced. My code works good for single words, but if I try to replace a phrase with a space, it doesn't work. What I have is a HashMap that contains what I need to search for in the file.

```
 HashMap<String, Integer> hm = new HashMap<>();

            hm.put("null",0);
            hm.put("max",1);
            hm.put("Do not repeat",2);
            hm.put("names",3);
```

I then iterate through the HashMap and replace the strings with the word if the file contains it.

```
                    for (String key : hm.keySet()) {
                        String check = key;
                        System.out.println(check);

                        text = text.toLowerCase(Locale.ROOT).replaceAll(check, "WRONG");
                    }
                    String new = text;
```

This isn't working if I have a space in the words like for "Do not repeat". How can I get this to work for phrases and not just single words? It completely skips over the phrases and outputs the new file with only the single words replaced.

Comment: It's not the spaces, it's the uppercased D, no?

Comment: BTW, if you're wanting to replace the literal string, you should consider quoting it, e.g. `Pattern.quote(check)`, to avoid surprising things with metacharacters. Or just use `replace`, ofc.

Comment: Thank you! I feel so silly! Do you happen to know a way to do this without turning the text file to lowercase?

Comment: Do you mean, how to do it case-insensitively?

Comment: Yeah, I would like to check without having to change all the letters in the file to lowercase!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not to do with the spaces, it's because of the upper-cased D.

```
text.toLowerCase(Locale.ROOT)
```

will make a string containing only lower-cased letters, so `"Do not repeat"` will not be found in it.

You can make `replaceAll` case insensitive by passing [the appropriate flag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5054995/how-to-replace-case-insensitive-literal-substrings-in-java):

```
text = text.replaceAll("(?i)" + check, "WRONG");
```

Note that you might run into problems with metacharacters in the strings you are searching for. If you might include things with e.g. periods (`.`), you should quote `check`:

```
text = text.replaceAll("(?i)" + Pattern.quote(check), "WRONG");
```

Also, because you're not considering word boundaries, you might run into the [Scunthorpe problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scunthorpe_problem).

Comment: Perfect! Exactly what I wanted to learn!. Thank you!