# How to check a String for multiple condition in Java?

Tags: java, string, replace

I am trying to check for multiple conditions, between DATA, data, dAta, daTa, datA etc.

and replace any of these with "Data". How can I do that?

```
    private String removeBrackets(final String line)
    {
        String lowerCaseData = null;
        String removeLeft = line.replace("[", "");
        String removeRight = removeLeft.replace("]", "");
        if (removeRight.contains("Data"))
        {
            lowerCaseData = removeRight.replace("Data", "data");
            return Character.toUpperCase(lowerCaseData.charAt(0)) + lowerCaseData.substring(1);
        }
        else
        return Character.toUpperCase(removeRight.charAt(0)) + removeRight.substring(1);
    }
```

Comment: You can just do `if(removeRight.toLowercase().equals("data"))` then go ahead with the remaining bits?

Comment: Or use ``if (removeRight.equalsIgnoreCase("data"))``

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it like this.  The `(?i)` is a flag that says ignore case.

```
String s = "Other text Data daTa DATA data dATa";
s = s.replaceAll("(?i)data", "Data");
System.out.println(s);
```

prints

```
Other text Data Data Data Data Data
```

Answer (score 2):

You can work with Java Regular Expressions (RegEx) and the replaceAll(String regex, String replacement) function.

Basically, you replace - case insensitive - all "data" (or "DAta", "DATA", "data" and so on...) with "Data".

```
private String removeBrackets(final String line)
{
    return line.replaceAll("(?i)data", "Data");
}
```

which outputs (when the input is not more than "data" in any case):

```
"Data"
```

***In general***, it's this principle:

```
String input = "FOODATAFOO";
output = input.replaceAll("(?i)data", "Data");
System.out.println(output);
```

which outputs:

```
FOODataFOO
```

I found the solution in this Stack Overflow question:
[How to replace case-insensitive literal substrings in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5054995/how-to-replace-case-insensitive-literal-substrings-in-java)

This is a link to the w3schools, where you can learn about RegEx in Java: https://www.w3schools.com/java/java_regex.asp

You can learn more about the "i Modifier" of RegEx here [it's in JavaScript, but the modifier functionality is the same]: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_regexp_i.asp

Here are some informations about the `replaceAll()` method: https://www.javatpoint.com/java-string-replaceall