# How to append two string using Matcher in java

Tags: java, regex

I've two string token, I'm checking the pattern and send both the token back with `":"` delimiter.
**Input :**

```
String oldToken = "Bearer IdmH0VCifziTjHNGfyKfK9YCoEsy6nTDI";
String newToken = "Bearer IdsfdWeRrrfziTjHNGfyKfK9YCoEsy6nTDI";
```

**Output:**

```
IdmH0VCifziTjHNGfyKfK9YCoEsy6nTDI : IdsfdWeRrrfziTjHNGfyKfK9YCoEsy6nTDI
```

**Please find my code below:**

```
public class TestToken {
    public static  void main(String[] args) {
        String oldToken = "Bearer IdmH0VCifziTjHNGfyKfK9YCoEsy6nTDI";
        String newToken = "Bearer IdsfdWeRrrfziTjHNGfyKfK9YCoEsy6nTDI";
        String result = getToken(oldToken, newToken);
        System.out.println("result: " +result);
    }

    private static String getToken(String oldtoken, String newToken) {
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(
                "^Bearer (?<token>[a-zA-Z0-9-._~+/]+)=*$",
                Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);

        Matcher matcher =null;
        if (StringUtils.startsWithIgnoreCase(oldtoken, "bearer")) {
            matcher = pattern.matcher(oldtoken);
            boolean matchResult = matcher.matches();
        }
        return matcher.group("token");
    }
}
```

How can I combine both these token in this case and return it back. Any help would be really appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Why use regex at all? And all of the rest to make sure you don't get "Bearer"? `str.split(" ", 2)[1]` gets you the token and ignores `Bearer`. Or at most just replace "Bearer" win the string with nothing and you still get the token. Then just concatenate the tokens with `:` between them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check match the pattern in both, `oldtoken` and `newtoken` and combine the matches.

**Demo:**

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String oldToken = "Bearer IdmH0VCifziTjHNGfyKfK9YCoEsy6nTDI";
        String newToken = "Bearer IdsfdWeRrrfziTjHNGfyKfK9YCoEsy6nTDI";
        String result = getToken(oldToken, newToken);
        System.out.println("result: " + result);
    }

    private static String getToken(String oldtoken, String newToken) {
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^Bearer (?<token>[a-zA-Z0-9-._~+/]+)=*$", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
        String result = "";
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(oldtoken);
        if (matcher.find()) {
            result += matcher.group(1);
        }

        result += " : ";

        matcher = pattern.matcher(newToken);
        if (matcher.find()) {
            result += matcher.group(1);
        } else {
            result = "";
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
result: IdmH0VCifziTjHNGfyKfK9YCoEsy6nTDI : IdsfdWeRrrfziTjHNGfyKfK9YCoEsy6nTDI
```

Answer (score 1):

Without using regular expressions at all: split the string on space and take the second part. You can add a limit of `2` just in case you expect any other spaces later in the string.

```java
private static String getToken(String oldtoken, String newToken) {
    String s1 = oldtoken.split(" ", 2)[1];
    String s2 = newToken.split(" ", 2)[1];

    return s1 + " : " + s2;
}
```

---

If you really wish to use regular expressions, it's better to do it for a [case-insensitive replacement](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5055036/) to remove "Bearer" from the front of the string:

```java
private static String getToken(String oldtoken, String newToken) {
    String removePattern = "(?i)^Bearer\\s+";
    String s1 = oldtoken.replaceFirst(removePattern, "");
    String s2 = newToken.replaceFirst(removePattern, "");

    return s1 + " : " + s2;
}
```

This pattern might be overly generic with no use. It is case-insensitive and it also matches any amount of spaces after "Bearer". Using `"^Bearer "` as replacement pattern is very likely enough.

---

It is also possible to do the the above without using any regex at all by taking the substring after "Bearer ".

```java
private static String getToken(String oldtoken, String newToken) {
    int removeBearer = "Bearer ".length();
    String s1 = oldtoken.substring(removeBearer);
    String s2 = newToken.substring(removeBearer);

    return s1 + " : " + s2;
}
```

You can also just hardcode the length, as there are 7 characters in that string and that is always going to be the case. But leaving it there makes it easy to see why 7 is chosen.